# Suppress output from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

How do you stop the output from subprocess.Popen from being output?  Printing can sometimes be slow if there is a great deal of it.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [python - How to hide output of subprocess - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess) (Popen versus call)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to totally throw it away:

```
import subprocess
import os
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as fp:
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(("[command]",), stdout=fp)
```

If you are using Python 2.5, you will need `from __future__ import with_statement`, or just don't use `with`.

Comment: This no longer works. Please update. TypeError: popen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stdout'

Answer (score 30):

In Python 3.3+ you could use [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL), to suppress the output:

```
from subprocess import DEVNULL, STDOUT, check_call

check_call([cmd, arg1, arg2], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Remove `stderr=STDOUT` if you don't want to suppress `stderr` also.

Comment: This also worked for me (Python 3.6, Ubuntu Linux OS):

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=DEVNULL)

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me (Python 3.6, Ubuntu Linux OS):

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=DEVNULL)
```

-This assumes you want non blocking call and no junk in the console from the cmd.