# Suppress print to console with os.popen? - Python

Tags: python, unix, operating-system, subprocess, popen

When using the `popen` to unix commands, i get certain outputs to the console.

I understand that `subprocess.popen` has features that supresses the output. [Suppress output from subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082623/suppress-output-from-subprocess-popen)

**Does** `os.popen` **have the same supression feature?**

please note that I've pipes in my unix command and i can't get `subprocess.Popen` to work. My command looks like this

`$ echo "es ist also grotesk , wenn herr jospin die europäische richtlinie und die britische datumsgestützte ausfuhrregelung gröblichst mißachtet und durch seine eigenen bedingungen zu ersetzen trachtet ." | treetagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german-utf8`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082623/suppress-output-from-subprocess-popen

Comment: Whee, TreeTagger! How I don't miss remote-controlling you via the commandline.

Comment: it's much better than messing around with the wrapper classes. Much cleaner to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use pipes, do not use `os.popen`:

```
import subprocess

text = "es ist also ..."
tt = subprocess.Popen('treetagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german-utf8', 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
tagged, stderr = tt.communicate(txt)
```

Back in the day when I was the processing pipeline developer for the [Text+Berg corpus](http://www.textberg.ch/), I wrote a wrapper class for the TreeTagger, circumventing the wrapper scripts (which are of dubious quality anyway). Unfortunately, the code is proprietary.

Comment: my wrapper did very crazily simple things to get the lemmas =) http://pastebin.com/2Qnz4yFc

Comment: Contact me (see my profile) and I can get you in touch with the people that own this code, they might give it to you.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use "pipes" and `os.popen`? What's the difference between `os.popen` and `subprocess.Popen`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `subprocess.check_output` instead.  It will capture the output in a string for you, and will also do error checking automatically (throwing an error if the command fails).

Comment: it's sort of weird, i want the outputs in strings but not the error output. how can i do that?

Comment: See my answer. You can have the result in string.

Comment: I think `check_output` does put the command's stdout in the result string but leaves the command's stderr hooked up to the calling script's stderr.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: i think it's not working due to the pipes, my command looks like this `echo "es ist also grotesk , wenn herr jospin die europäische richtlinie und die britische datumsgestützte ausfuhrregelung gröblichst mißachtet und durch seine eigenen bedingungen zu ersetzen trachtet ." | treetagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german-utf8`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['command'], 
           stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).