# Hide informational messages when using Apache Tika command-line

Tags: python, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika from within Python as follows, to extract images/attachments from PDF files.

```
subprocess.call(["java", "-jar", "./tika-app-1.10.jar","--extract"+data_dir])
```

This leads to messages being shown for each extracted attachment, such as "*Extracting 'image1.jpg' (image/jpeg) to ./image1.jpg*". Is there a way I can hide these types of messages from the output?

Comment: capture and discard stdout from your process?

Comment: Good suggestion, I'm looking into `subprocess.Popen` to do just that. How do I discard the output though?

Comment: I found the solution from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082623/suppress-output-from-subprocess-popen), using `Popen` instead of `call`